# Google+ share counts are not showing

Tags: share, google-plus-one

I am using Google+ JavaScript API and currently my Google+ share counts are not showing on the website.

Note: I am using Google+ JavaScript API

This is the code I tried

```html
<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<script src="apis.google.com/js/platform.js" ; async defer></script>
<!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="vertical-bubble" data-height="60">
</div>
```

Comment: <!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="vertical-bubble" data-height="60"></div>

Comment: This is the code i tried

Comment: I can confirm this problem. It seems Google did some changes and counting does not work any more. See https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/ - no counts there, too.

Comment: Thanks Radek Svitil   for the advice. any chance for retrieving share counts?

Comment: I am afraid this is a feature, not a bug. See https://plus.google.com/110610523830483756510/posts/Z1FfzduveUo
Google apparently wants to follow Twitter way and remove counting from its buttons...

Comment: @RadekSvítil Then people will remove their buttons

Comment: I am about to remove it because it have no idea whether anyone is using it or not. Is there any place this data is available, like webmaster tools?.. Is g+ even has any worth any longer when it comes to SERP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google may have done this to speed up the load time of the Google Plus buttons.

https://plus.google.com/110610523830483756510/posts/Z1FfzduveUo

Answer (score 8):

They have been retired now so the share counts are no longer available.